# How do you set the color changes for all pages?

Tags: php, css, color-scheme

I have a menu that lets you select color schemes, but i can only figure out how to do it on one page without making different links for all of the pages, is there an easier way than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cookie, or store it in your session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['scheme'] = 'blue;
```